# symfony swiftmailer variable line breaks

Tags: symfony, email, twig, newline, swiftmailer

I'm trying to get new lines in my email template, but for some reason it doesn't work.

My Controller:

```
$content = $postData['name']. ' \n \n ' .$postData['address'];
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('test')
            ->setFrom($session->get('email'))
            ->setTo('myemail@gmail.com')
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'email.html.twig',
                    array('content' => $content)
                ),
                'text/html'
            )
        ;
```

My twig:

```
{{ content | nl2br }}
```

The result I get:

```
name \n \n address
```

In stead of '\n' I also tried using '\r\n' and '< br />', but no new lines neither in the email I get.

Comment: Put your `\n`'s in double quotes like `$postData['name']. " \n \n " .$postData['address']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: `.' \n \n '.` to `.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.`